# C# Windows Forms, I'm trying to Update a Label in Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

I am trying to update a Label in a Thread.  I have tried multiple different methods and still can't update my labels text here is my code

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    new Thread(SampleFunction).Start();
}
private void setLabel1TextSafe(string txt)
{
    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = txt));
        return;
    }
    label1.Text = txt;
}
public void AppendText(string value)
{
    label1.Text += value;
}
void SampleFunction()
{
    // Gets executed on a seperate thread and 
    // doesn't block the UI while sleeping
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        setLabel1TextSafe("Heya");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

There is no error being cast but the label text is not being changed or updated  Anyone can help? Thank You

Comment: Thank You For the Edit I was having problem with code blocks @reza-aghaei

Comment: You're welcome :) Your codes seems working. Do you have any other threads or `Thread.Sleep()` somewhere else in your form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: why should ir be supposed to change, if you are always send the same value "Heya"? Try sending another value and see if it change

Comment: Heya is just a test variable it should be changing from "Label1" to "heya" in the thread @Sameh

Comment: No I don't have any other Time.Sleep() but I'm using the mjpegprocessor.dll could that be it? @reza

Comment: You code works perfectly fine for me. I see the updated value in the label. You need to either create a [mcve] or delete this question.

Comment: @SamehDeabes - I tried exactly that in my test. I did `setLabel1TextSafe("Heya" + i);` and I saw the label update as intended. This question is unanswerable until the OP provides code that replicates the issue.